# background color drastically brighter on mobile, any solutions?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, samsung-mobile

I have a nice calm redish background i've given to a site i'm building, and really enjoy the color scheme. I had already checked mobile using chromes dev tools, but decided to look on my mobile phone just to make sure. Here's what the mobile *should* look like:

[image]

The problem is that on my actual phone (samsung s7 edge), the red is an extreme bright red. It's unbearable to look at, yet when I screenshot it and move the image over to my desktop, It looks like this smooth calm red again. Is there anyway to account for mobile phones weird color profile?

Comment: Samsung family give more live for the colors, it's looks like fun, but it's true, i suggest you change the color...keep in mind every device show the color in different ways.

Comment: It just depends on the screen devices and settings... This color does not look smooth at all anyway.

Comment: What's the hex/rgb value of that color by curiosity? I have to agree with Simon though, that's a pretty "loud" color for a base contrast in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Every device show colors in different way,it's okay that on desktop its looks a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your CSS. This will change the body's background color when your site is shown in the mobile view.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: /* add lighter color here */
    }
  
  }
```